# Doxygen freezes Generating docs for compound

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to generate the documentation from an ASP.NET project.  I'm using Doxygen 1.8.13 (64bit) on windows 10.

Processing seems to have stopped (for at least the last 2 hours) and the process shows the following :

`Generating docs for compound COMPANY_NAME::PRODUCT_FAMILY::WebServices::SERVICE...`

It has successfully generated other docs - it just seems to freeze when it reaches this point - have tried multiple times.

I've tried running with the -b undocumented flag, but I have no idea what is causing this issue.  The project contains references to c# projects and MVC / ASP.NET System assemblies.

How can I get a more detailed output from doxygen to see why this is taking so long?  I realise that this question doesn't give a lot of information - but I really don't know how to find

I have been able to test doxygen on a smaller c# asp.net mvc website, and it semms to work ok.

Comment: Indeed not a lot of information. Is it really frozen or just slow? Can you run the test on Linux as well and at the moment the program "freezes" attach to the process with gdb and see where the process hangs out? (Maybe something similar is possible on windows). Do you have any special settings in youtr Doxyfile ? Otherwise please try to reduce the program / number of files to a small self contained example.